# VBA to protect an Excel sheet but allow sort, autofilter, charts, copy

Tags: vba, excel

My workbook consists of almost 25 sheets, I want to protect 11 sheets. My criteria for protecting are as follows:

```
1. User cannot delete or modify any cell
2. User should be able to use SORT, AUTOFILTER, drop down selection from COMBO BOXES
3. Most of the sheets contain charts, they should be updated as per the user selection
4. User should not be able to see the formulas in the formula bar
5. User should be able to copy the data
```

I have tried all the general options in Excel, which does all the above work, but they leave the cells unlocked, which means user can delete the contents

Thus I hope this can be achieved only by a macro, please help.

Comment: are you worried about deleting the contents or the cell?

Comment: @siddharth-rout yes I am worried somebody might accidentally delete a cell content

Comment: Did you see the answer that I posted?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried all the general options in Excel, which does all the above work, but they leave the cells unlocked, which means user can delete the contents

Since every thing else works for you, I will not try to address those. With already what you have, add this code in the worksheet code area

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim rng As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each rng In Target
        If rng.Value = "" Then
            Application.Undo
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, the macro restores the deleted cells, but if the user modifies the cell, it is allowing that. I am sorry if I was not clear enough, these cells basically contain formulas, and I have to unlock them in order to enable sort/auto filter etc, which leaves them vulnerable. Could you please change the code, so that the user is not able to modify the cell contents.